# Concat Date As Text

Tags: excel-2007, concatenation, excel-formula

I am attempting the following formula:

`=concatenate(A1, " ", B1, " - ", C1)`

Where column A is text, B and C are dates.  The concatenate function returns the numerical value of the date, rather than the text value.  How do I fix this?

Comment: might be helpful if you can indicate what language it is

Comment: It's in Excel 2007, as indicated by the tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use TEXT

```
=CONCATENATE(A1," ",TEXT(B1,"dd mmm yyyy")," - ",TEXT(C1,"dd/mm/yyyy"))
```

Comment: Awesome!  I was playing with that, but I was missing the "dd/mm/yyyy"